# Ubuntu 20.04 - No wifi adapter found (DELL Precision 7760)

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, dell, iwlwifi

I have been tested all the solutions that I could found online so far, non of them worked for me. The laptop connects to the wired internet but not wifi.

**Laptop info:**

```
saeed@saeed-Precision-7760:~$ uname -r
5.11.0-34-generic
```

```
saeed@saeed-Precision-7760:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path       Device          Class          Description
=========================================================
                               system         Precision 7760 (0A6A)
/0                             bus            0H3D01
/0/1                           memory         1MiB BIOS
/0/400                         processor      11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11950H @ 2.60GHz
/0/400/701                     memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/400/702                     memory         10MiB L2 cache
/0/400/703                     memory         24MiB L3 cache
/0/700                         memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/1000                        memory         64GiB System Memory
/0/1000/0                      memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3467 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/1000/1                      memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3467 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/1000/2                      memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3467 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/1000/3                      memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3467 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/100                         bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1                       bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1/0     /dev/fb0        display        NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/1/0.1                   multimedia     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/2                       display        Intel Corporation
/0/100/4                       generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/6                       generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/7                       bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/7.1                     bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/a                       generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/d                       bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/d/0     usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/d/1     usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/d.2                     bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/e                       storage        Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
/0/100/12                      communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/14                      bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/14/0    usb3            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/3                  multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/0/5                  generic        58200
/0/100/14/0/e                  communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/1    usb4            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                    memory         RAM memory
/0/100/15                      bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/15.1                    bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/16                      communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/16.3                    communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/19                      bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c                      bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c/0                    network        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c.2                    bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c.2/0                  generic        RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1f                      bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.3                    multimedia     Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.4                    bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.5                    bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.6    enp0s31f6       network        Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM
/0/6                           bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/6/0                         storage        KIOXIA Corporation
/0/0                           system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                           system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/3                           generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/4                           input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/5                           generic        PnP device DLL0a6a
/0/7                           system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/8                           system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/9                           system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/a                           system         PnP device PNP0c02
/1                             power          DELL CR72X16
/2                             power          
/3             /dev/nvme0      storage        KXG70PNV2T04 NVMe KIOXIA 2048GB
/3/1           /dev/nvme0n1    disk           2048GB NVMe namespace
/3/1/1                         volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/3/1/2         /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         1907GiB EXT4 volume
```

```
saeed@saeed-Precision-7760:~$ lspci 
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a36 (rev 05)
0000:00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a01 (rev 05)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a60 (rev 01)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 05)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a2b (rev 05)
0000:00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a2d (rev 05)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a17 (rev 05)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1f (rev 05)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 43fc (rev 11)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 43ed (rev 11)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 43ef (rev 11)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43e8 (rev 11)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43e9 (rev 11)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 43e0 (rev 11)
0000:00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 43e3 (rev 11)
0000:00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43ad (rev 11)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43b9 (rev 11)
0000:00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43ba (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4389 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 43c8 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 43a3 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43a4 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM (rev 11)
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 249c (rev a1)
0000:01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228b (rev a1)
0000:92:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
0000:93:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a0f (rev 05)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation Device 000d
```

```
saeed@saeed-Precision-7760:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list 
0000:92:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4020]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
saeed@saeed-Precision-7760:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:92:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:b7200000-b7203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 11
       serial: 38:14:28:7c:e9:94
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-34-generic duplex=full firmware=0.4-4 ip=192.168.50.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:147 memory:b7380000-b739ffff
```

```
saeed@saeed-Precision-7760:~$ dmesg | grep wifi
[    2.696361] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.704836] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.704866] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    2.705362] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.956421] Modules linked in: soundwire_bus nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) mac80211(+) coretemp(+) fjes(+) dell_wmi(+) snd_soc_core libarc4 dell_smbios snd_compress kvm_intel i915(+) dcdbas ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine uvcvideo(+) hid_sensor_gyro_3d snd_seq_midi hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_vmalloc processor_thermal_device industrialio_triggered_buffer videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event kfifo_buf kvm hid_sensor_iio_common btusb snd_rawmidi industrialio videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul iwlwifi snd_pcm btrtl videobuf2_common ghash_clmulni_intel drm_kms_helper btbcm snd_seq_device aesni_intel btintel videodev snd_timer ucsi_acpi(+) processor_thermal_rfim cec mei_me typec_ucsi crypto_simd processor_thermal_mbox bluetooth snd input_leds(+) rc_core i2c_algo_bit cryptd processor_thermal_rapl fb_sys_fops glue_helper cros_ec_ishtp ecdh_generic intel_pmt_telemetry syscopyarea intel_rapl_common serio_raw efi_pstore dell_wmi_sysman(+) cfg80211 dell_wmi_descriptor sysfillrect mc wmi_bmof
[    2.956989] Modules linked in: soundwire_bus nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) mac80211(+) coretemp(+) fjes(+) dell_wmi(+) snd_soc_core libarc4 dell_smbios snd_compress kvm_intel i915(+) dcdbas ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine uvcvideo(+) hid_sensor_gyro_3d snd_seq_midi hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_vmalloc processor_thermal_device industrialio_triggered_buffer videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event kfifo_buf kvm hid_sensor_iio_common btusb snd_rawmidi industrialio videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul iwlwifi snd_pcm btrtl videobuf2_common ghash_clmulni_intel drm_kms_helper btbcm snd_seq_device aesni_intel btintel videodev snd_timer ucsi_acpi(+) processor_thermal_rfim cec mei_me typec_ucsi crypto_simd processor_thermal_mbox bluetooth snd input_leds(+) rc_core i2c_algo_bit cryptd processor_thermal_rapl fb_sys_fops glue_helper cros_ec_ishtp ecdh_generic intel_pmt_telemetry syscopyarea intel_rapl_common serio_raw efi_pstore dell_wmi_sysman(+) cfg80211 dell_wmi_descriptor sysfillrect mc wmi_bmof
[    2.957513] Modules linked in: soundwire_bus nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) mac80211(+) coretemp(+) fjes(+) dell_wmi(+) snd_soc_core libarc4 dell_smbios snd_compress kvm_intel i915(+) dcdbas ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine uvcvideo(+) hid_sensor_gyro_3d snd_seq_midi hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_vmalloc processor_thermal_device industrialio_triggered_buffer videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event kfifo_buf kvm hid_sensor_iio_common btusb snd_rawmidi industrialio videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul iwlwifi snd_pcm btrtl videobuf2_common ghash_clmulni_intel drm_kms_helper btbcm snd_seq_device aesni_intel btintel videodev snd_timer ucsi_acpi(+) processor_thermal_rfim cec mei_me typec_ucsi crypto_simd processor_thermal_mbox bluetooth snd input_leds(+) rc_core i2c_algo_bit cryptd processor_thermal_rapl fb_sys_fops glue_helper cros_ec_ishtp ecdh_generic intel_pmt_telemetry syscopyarea intel_rapl_common serio_raw efi_pstore dell_wmi_sysman(+) cfg80211 dell_wmi_descriptor sysfillrect mc wmi_bmof
[    2.958069] Modules linked in: soundwire_bus nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) mac80211(+) coretemp(+) fjes(+) dell_wmi(+) snd_soc_core libarc4 dell_smbios snd_compress kvm_intel i915(+) dcdbas ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine uvcvideo(+) hid_sensor_gyro_3d snd_seq_midi hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_vmalloc processor_thermal_device industrialio_triggered_buffer videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event kfifo_buf kvm hid_sensor_iio_common btusb snd_rawmidi industrialio videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul iwlwifi snd_pcm btrtl videobuf2_common ghash_clmulni_intel drm_kms_helper btbcm snd_seq_device aesni_intel btintel videodev snd_timer ucsi_acpi(+) processor_thermal_rfim cec mei_me typec_ucsi crypto_simd processor_thermal_mbox bluetooth snd input_leds(+) rc_core i2c_algo_bit cryptd processor_thermal_rapl fb_sys_fops glue_helper cros_ec_ishtp ecdh_generic intel_pmt_telemetry syscopyarea intel_rapl_common serio_raw efi_pstore dell_wmi_sysman(+) cfg80211 dell_wmi_descriptor sysfillrect mc wmi_bmof
[    2.966148] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    3.120805] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[    3.369779] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    3.369783] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.369786] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[    3.573763] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway
[    3.585968] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

**BIOS info:**

```
saeed@saeed-Precision-7760:~$ sudo mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
```

**What I tried:**

```
saeed@saeed-Precision-7760:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libva-wayland2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser
The following packages will be upgraded:
  chromium-browser
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,546 kB/1,594 kB of archives.
After this operation, 164 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3 [1,546 kB]
Fetched 1,546 kB in 5s (281 kB/s)                
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 193383 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the chromium snap
snap "chromium" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
=> Snap installation complete
=> Connecting the password-manager-service interface (LP: #1836616)
Unpacking chromium-browser (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) over (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.11.0-34-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.11.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up chromium-browser (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-34-generic
```

Did not worked!

I also installed ***iwlwifi*** driver using ***synaptic***. Did not work!

I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, no luck either!

**My question:**

Is this problem related to the Ubuntu Kernel? Is there any way that I can fix this? (I can connect to internet using Ethernet)

Comment: The fix is amazingly easy! Please see the duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!